# Key number press to submit form

Tags: javascript, html, onkeypress

It's a page for Handheld Scanner Website (PocketPC), so for easy handling of the device when number 1 is pressed in the keyboard, bottom 1 is submitted. I don't know why it's not working for me.

```js
function check1(e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == 49) {
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onkeypress="check1(event)" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hard to help you with so little details. What does "not working" mean? A [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) reproducing the bug would help

Comment: @Tdy done. made an edit on behalf of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach event to the entire document and not just that `<input>` in this case. This is because you want to trigger the action event if the `<input>` is not in focus. You code activated only if it is on focus.

I have made the change:

**HAVE A LOOK AT THE SNIPPET:**

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '49') {
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: approved ur edit. yes "no need for `onkeypress`" anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `onkeypress` event is triggered on the whole document, not your input button. So you will need to set your event handler like so:

```
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 49) { // note camel casing: keyCode, not KeyCode
        form1.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, nothing happens when key number 1 is pressed. But if i change the keyCode to 13 (enter key) it works.

Answer (score 0):

It work:

```
$(function(){
  $('*').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode=='49'){
        document.forms[0].submit();
      }       
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**A jQuery Approach**

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e){
if(e.keyCode === 49){
    $('#form1').submit();
}
})
```